# figure out the CRC bytes

Tags: crc

I am trying to write some code to figure out a CRC on the following byte sequence for an AI algorithm class project, and would like to seek some suggestions from this forum.

For example, the following bytes patterns are provided:

```
0f81265b6341
0f80265b63eb
0f83265b634a
0f89265b636d

0f81265b6269
0f83265b6262
0f80265b62c3
0f89265b6245

0f81265b594c
0f83265b5947
0f80265b59e6

0f81265b5A34
0f83265b5A3F
0f80265b5A9E
0f89265b5A18
```

I am trying to make an algorithm to see which bytes are involved and also which algorithm to try to deduce the final checksum byte. The final goal is to teach a machine how to do CRC by a learning process.

Comment: Seems very much like a "please do my homework" question.

Comment: it is sort of a research project, not really a home work.  I am trying to see if a algorithm can be written to solve CRC on its own.  First step is not much of anything, just trying to use any known technique or brute force method, but i want to progress into something a little smarter as the project progress.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Reveng](http://sourceforge.net/projects/reveng/).

Comment: Yes, reveng found it pretty easily.  Still working towards the goal of some kind of self learning algorithm.  Thank you for the pointer.